# File path name for NumPy's loadtxt()

Tags: python, file, numpy

I was wondering if somebody had some information on how to load a CSV file using NumPy's loadtxt(). For some reason it claims that there is no such file or directory, when clearly there is. I've even copy/pasted the full path (with and without the leading / for root), but to no avail.

```
from numpy import *
FH = loadtxt("/Users/groenera/Desktop/file.csv")
```

or

```
from numpy import *
FH = loadtxt("Users/groenera/Desktop/file.csv")
```

The [documentation for loadtxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) is very unhelpful about this.

Comment: Unrelated, but: `from numpy import *` -- don't do this.  It'll lead to very hard-to-diagnose bugs in your code because many builtin functions will be shadowed by similarly-named numpy versions with dangerously different behaviour in certain cases.  Either import functions explicitly `from numpy import loadtxt` or use the standard abbreviation, `import numpy as np` and then `np.loadtxt`.

Comment: Can you copy 'file.csv' file current working directory and try out. From the documentation, I don't think so you can use file path.

Comment: Show the result of the following when run in a terminal: `cd /Users/groenera/Desktop; pwd; ls -l`

Comment: @DSM Good advice about the potential namespace conflicts.

Comment: @rajpy I've done so and it works when the script and the csv file are in the same directory, but this is not what I want. The reason why I'm so insistent on it being in a different directory is because my script outputs data files of its own which need to be separate from the location I've placed my data files.

Comment: @Warren Weckesser That's the first thing I tried. The directory exists and the files are there.

Comment: "Trust, but verify."  I understood that's what you said; I just wanted to see it for myself.  Have you tried the suggestion in @askewchan's answer?

Comment: I just tried it. Although my problem was that I'm importing many modules in a bad way (using from MODULE import *). I believe there is a loadtxt namespace clash, so what fixed it for me was to do: import numpy as np (then make sure I'm using np.loadtxt() explicitly).

Comment: scipy's `loadtxt` (i.e. `scipy.loadtxt`) is just an alias for `numpy.loadtxt` (i.e. they are the same thing), so I don't see how using the name from scipy would have caused the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably not a `loadtxt` problem. Try simply

```
f = open("/Users/groenera/Desktop/file.csv")
```

to make sure it is `loadtxt`'s fault. Also, try using a Unicode string:

```
f = open(u"/Users/groenera/Desktop/file.csv")
```

Comment: The open command seems to work. 

On a completely different note, though, importing numpy loadtxt like so:

    import numpy as np
    f = np.loadtxt('/Users/groenera/Desktop/file.csv')

seemed to do the trick. As far as I knew there wasn't a function in the standard library called loadtxt. I think the problem was that SciPy has a loadtxt function, and since I was importing everything from both I wasn't paying attention to which one was being called (and assuming that it was NumPy's version).

For the future is there a way to test where a function is being called from in a situation like this?

Comment: @astromax `scipy.loadtxt` _is_ `numpy.loadtxt`, so I'd be very surprised if that was the problem (scipy imports numpy functions and provides them).  You can see what file it comes from with `<function>.__module__`.  So, for me `np.loadtxt.__module__` returns `'numpy.lib.npyio'` and so does `scipy.loadtxt.__module__`

Comment: Uh oh. Well, it's entirely possible that I just had an error in the path (it is a pretty long path). But from what I remember importing numpy differently is what fixed it for me. Thanks for all of the help, though!

Comment: @astromax Hm.. It's also possible that some other system state was screwed up somehow, and the good old restart/reload is what fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

You might have forgot the double slash, "//". Some machines require this.

So instead of

```
FH = loadtxt("/Users/groenera/Desktop/file.csv")
```

do this:

```
FH = loadtxt("C:\\Users\\groenera\\Desktop\\file.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using [PyCharm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PyCharm), Python 3.5.2.

Right-click on your project and open a file with 'planet.csv' and paste your text.

Add a header to each column.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('planet.csv',sep = "\n")
print (data)
```